# Invalid parameter number PDO

Tags: php, pdo

got this:

```
public function Register($uname,$pass,$mail)
    {
        try
        {
            $new_password = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO users(username,email,password)
            VALUES(:uname, :mail, :pass)");

            $stmt->bindparam(":uname, $uname");
            $stmt->bindparam(":mail, $mail");
            $stmt->bindparam(":pass, $new_password");
            $stmt->execute();
        }
        catch (PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

when I am trying to register it throws me an error:SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound. Was looking through the internet for the answers, but didn't find it yet, maybe you, guys , got some ideas?

Comment: I recommend you to change the variable names to some "better" ones. Read this: [Clean, high quality code](https://www.butterfly.com.au/blog/website-development/clean-high-quality-code-a-guide-on-how-to-become-a-better-programmer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `bindparam(':name', $name)` instead of `bindparam(':name, $name')`. The first argument is a name of parameter slug, and the second argument is a variable you want to bind.

```
public function Register($uname,$pass,$mail)
{
    try
    {
        $new_password = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO users(username,email,password)
        VALUES(:uname, :mail, :pass)");

        //note the quotes!
        $stmt->bindParam(":uname", $uname);
        $stmt->bindParam(":mail", $mail);
        $stmt->bindParam(":pass", $new_password);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```